# Is JPA Embeddable a Value Object and Why Can't it Represent a Table

Tags: jpa, entity, domain-driven-design, value-objects, embeddable

PROBLEM: I have read-only data in a table. Its rows have no id - only composite key define its identity. I want it as a Value Object (in DDD terms) in my app.

RESEARCH: But if I put an `@Embeddable` annotation instead of `@Entity` with `@Id id` field, then `javax.persistence.metamodel` doesn't see it and says `Not an embeddable` on `Metamodel metamodel.embeddable(MyClass.class);`. I could wrap it with an @Entity class and autogenerate id, but this is not what I architectually intended to achieve.

QUESTION: Is JPA Embeddable a Value Object? Can Embeddable exist without a parent Entity and represent a Table?

Answer (score 2):

There are **many articles** on the topic that show this is a real JPA inconvenience:

- http://thepaulrayner.com/persisting-value-objects/
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-persisting-ddd-aggregates
- https://paucls.wordpress.com/2017/03/04/ddd-building-blocks-value-objects/
- https://medium.com/@benoit.averty/domain-driven-design-storing-value-objects-in-a-spring-application-with-a-relational-database-e7a7b555a0e4

Most of them suggest **solutions based on normalised relational database**, with a header-entity as one table and its value-objects as other separate tables.

My frustration was augmented with the necessity to integrate with a non-normalized read-only table. The **table had no id field and meant to store object-values**. No bindings with a header-entity table. To map it with JPA was a problem, because only entities with id are mapped.

The solution was to **wrap MyValueObject class with MyEntity class**, making MyValueObject its composite key:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "my_schema", name = "my_table")
public class MyEntity {

  @EmbeddedId MyValueObject valueObject;
}
```

As a slight hack, to bypass JPA requirements for default empty constructor and not to break the immutability of Value Object, we **add it as private and sacrifice final modifier for fields**. Privacy and absence of setters conforms the initial DDD idea of Value Object:

```
// @Value // Can't use, unfortunately.
@Embeddable
@Immutable
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(staticName = "private") // Makes MyValueObject() private.
public class MyValueObject implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "field_one")
  private String myString;

  @Column(name = "field_two")
  private Double myDouble;

  @Transient private Double notNeeded;
}
```

Also there is a handful Lombok's `@Value` annotaion to configure value objects.